# jQuery.click() call after onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have anchor tag witn inline onClick 
and with jQuery query I am also calling Click() event
can I call jQuery.Click after inline onClick.

```js
$("a:contains('Clear')").click(function() { //my Code });
```

```html
<a onclick="fun2()" href="javascript:{}"> 
                           Clear                    
</a>
```

Comment: show the code you have worked before?

Comment: Please provide some code, it's hard to determine exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: And why two click events ?

Comment: General advice: When using jQuery, don't use inline click handlers too. Best stick to jQuery handlers as they are more powerful (**and shown your code!**) :).

Comment: Apply the inline `onclick` function name inside the `jquery.click` end of the  function like this  `jquery.click(function(){},youronclickfunction(){})`

Comment: If you want to call another function after a click event, Why not to call it from the first function?.

Comment: @Leopard fun2() is system generated coming from Sharepoint and by using jquery i want to hide one section fun2()="$getClientControl(this).updateRefinementFilters()"

Comment: @prasad I want my jquery code execute after onClick so can i append my Code line after inline onClick dynamically

Comment: @pawankotak which one is the first `inline click` or `jquery click`

Comment: @prasad inline onClick is first and jQUery.click is second

Comment: @pawankotak see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mousedown` & `mouseup` event. Click event separate with two mousedown excute `fun2` & mouseup execute jquery function.see the console.log normal click first jquery is second

```js
$("a:contains('Clear')").mouseup(function() { 
console.log('i m jquery click')
});

function fun2(){
  console.log('i m a normal click')
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  href="javascript:{}" onmousedown="fun2()">Clear </a>
```

**or**

Include your onclick function name into jquery function with first line. like this below.After that line apply your code

```js
$("a:contains('Clear')").click(function() { 
  fun2();// call inline onclick function
//your code
console.log('i m jquery click')
});

function fun2(){
  console.log('i m a normal click')
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  href="javascript:{}" >Clear </a>
```

Comment: fun2() is using rest api with ajax call. <a onclick="Srch.Refinement.submitMultiRefinement('MMD1114', $getClientControl(this), false, false);$('.wrap-div').css('display','block');" href="javascript:{}">

Comment: Srch.Refinement* =fun2() and  $('.wrap-dvi')*=mycode